# Script not loaded in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, internet-explorer-9

I've been troubleshooting this problem with no luck. I'm not sure why my jQuery code isn't loaded in IE9. It's quite huge but it just basically detects svg docs in the DOM and manipulate them. Basically, this is how my code looks:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // init panzoom
    initPanZoom();

    function initPanZoom() {
        // get svg containers for each main tab
        var svgs = [$("#pcb").find("svg"), $("#gerber").find("svg")];

        $(".schematic-sheet").each(function(){
            svgs.push($(this).find("svg"));
        });

        var objPlaceholders = [];

        $.map(svgs, function(obj, index){
            objPlaceholders[index] = new PanZoom({
                svg: obj[0],
                viewportClass: "svgscale",
                userViewport: $("#user-viewport")[0]
            });

            obj.closest("div").find('.zoom-in').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                objPlaceholders[index].handleMouseClick(1.5);
            });
            obj.closest("div").find('.zoom-out').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                objPlaceholders[index].handleMouseClick(-1.5);
            });
            obj.closest("div").find('.reset').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                objPlaceholders[index].handleMouseClick(0);
            });
        });
     }
});
```

The weirdest thing is at first time you load it, `initPanZoom()` isn't called at all. After a few minutes, when you refresh, it's then called. So there must be something wrong I don't know. Please note that this only manifests in IE9.

**UPDATE**

I should also note that this code is loaded on a page that's inside an iframe. And I noticed that viewing the page directly in the browser sometimes resolves the issue.

Comment: What is your version of `jQuery`?

Comment: @PM77-1 It's `1.11.1`

Comment: What errors, if any, do you see in the console?

Comment: @aDroidman No errors unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` and later changing that to `$` so, please change it to `$` i.e `$( document ).ready(function() {`

Another thing you care calling that function into the `$( document ).ready(function() {` so you need to cut the whole function data out from the `function initPanZoom() { }` and use it directly. i.e.

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
   // get svg containers for each main tab
        var svgs = [$("#pcb").find("svg"), $("#gerber").find("svg")];

        $(".schematic-sheet").each(function(){
            svgs.push($(this).find("svg"));
        });

        var objPlaceholders = [];

        $.map(svgs, function(obj, index){
            objPlaceholders[index] = new PanZoom({
                svg: obj[0],
                viewportClass: "svgscale",
                userViewport: $("#user-viewport")[0]
            });

            obj.closest("div").find('.zoom-in').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                objPlaceholders[index].handleMouseClick(1.5);
            });
            obj.closest("div").find('.zoom-out').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                objPlaceholders[index].handleMouseClick(-1.5);
            });
            obj.closest("div").find('.reset').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                objPlaceholders[index].handleMouseClick(0);
            });
        });     
});
```